# mysql group_concat order by utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, internationalization

I have the following problem 
I have 3 table (all of the are used utf8 / utf8_general_ci encoding)
movies, channels, i also have 3 table  movie_channels which

is  just a combination of the other two with just 2 fields: movie_id,channel_id 
here is my channels table (code,name)

```
'1', 'ОРТ'
'2', 'ТК Спорт'
'3', 'ТК ТНВ'
'4', 'НТВ'
'5', 'НТВ+'
'6', 'TSN'
```

here is my movie_channels table (movie _id, channel_id) channel_id references `code` field in channels table

```
'19', '2'
'19', '6'
'95', '1'
'95', '4'
'96', '1'
'96', '4'
'97', '1'
'97', '4'
'98', '1'
'98', '4'
'99', '1'
'99', '4'
'100', '1'
'100', '4'
```

don't mind  quotes on id values. they are all ints of course, not chars, it's just pasting issue

for each  movie i need to display comma separated list  of channels 
i used mysql group_concat

```
select t.movie_id,( select group_concat(c.name) from 
movie_channels mc
join channels c  on mc.channel_id=c.code
where mc.movie_id = t.movie_id

order by code desc )as audio_channel from movies t
```

but I dont like the order of concat for movie_id  #19  i need the above sql to display TSN,ТК Спорт but it keeps returning me ТК Спорт,TSN . I tried to use order by  code desc with no luck ,tried  order by char_length(asc) with no success 
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for every movie you want to list all the channels that are showing that movie, you need something like this:

```
SELECT
  mc.movie_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS channels
FROM movie_channels AS mc
JOIN channels AS c
ON c.code = mc.channel_id
GROUP BY mc.movie_id
ORDER BY c.code DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [`ORDER BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) inside the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate to adjust the ordering of the grouped string.